# Using tinyXml2 in a C++ project

Tags: c++, tinyxml2

I am new to **tinyXml2**. I am trying to parse an `xml` file and print the text in the root tag. this is my code.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include "tinyxml2.h"

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    XMLDocument doc;
    doc.LoadFile("input.xml");
    const char *title = doc.FirstChildElement("root")->GetText();
    printf("%s\n", title);
    return 0;
}
```

On building this I get an error saying `XMLDocument was not declared in this scope`.

What is the problem?

Comment: How the contents of the XML file is relevant to the compiler error?

Answer (score 12):

You have to specify the namespace. Either add

```
using namespace tinyxml2;
```

to the beginning of your code, after the `#include` directives, or explicitly specify it when you declare `doc`:

```
tinyxml2::XMLDocument doc;
```

etc.